# JSON serialization/deserialization Alamofire, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, decodable

I have Alamofire request like this:

```
Alamofire.request("myurl", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData { (responseData) in

let data = responseData.data
            
do {
   let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(MYOBJECT.self, from: data)
} catch {
   print(error)
   }
}
```

MYOBJECTS comes from backend and it looks like this:

```
data class CountryObject(
   val country: String,
   val name: String,
) : ResponseObject
```

The problem is that (obviously) MYOBJECT doesnt conform to decodable object. This is the error => `Instance method 'decode(_:from:)' requires that 'MYOBJECT' conform to 'Decodable'`

My question is do I have to replicate the object? How do I conform this object to Decodable protocol? I also need to deserialize this object (JSON) from Alamofire, is my approach correct? Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Swift model corresponding to the backend model. Look at the `JSON` and make a model like this:

```
struct Country: Decodable {
    var country: String
    var name: String
}
```

And decode it using the above model, like if it's returning a single object:

```
let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: data)
```

If it's an array:

```
let country = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
```

Note: Use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to generate your model for your `JSON` quickly :).

Comment: Is there any way I can use my Kotlin class and make it Decodable?

Comment: No, you can't. You're receiving data as `JSON` which doesn't contain information about any particular language class.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `CountryObject` seems to be Kotlin and not Swift?

In Swift, having a class or struct conform to `Decodable` is just as easy as this:

```
struct CountryObject : Decodable {
    val country : String
    val name : String
}
```

Comment: Yes my CountyObject is in Kotlin! So in your answer I should replicate my object in swift?

Comment: Yes, you need a Swift version of CountryObject, or MYOBJECT, if that is the name of your class/struct.

Comment: Is there any way I can use my Kotlin class and make it Decodable?